# Failure INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK when install application on Android 2.3.5

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I try to install my Android application in HTC Explorer device(Android version - 2.3.5).It got following error in Android Studio,

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

1. Actually I want to support Android version 2.2 to 4.4 as single apk. Shall I want to change target SDK version to each version build or put latest api level is enough(As preferred by developer document)?
2. [In developer document table](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels),Android 2.3.5 not exist? why?

Comment: for your 2nd question, it may imply that there is no API change from 2.3.5 ~ 2.3.7

Comment: So version 2.3.5 is not a problem for my case.Then why application not install on HTC mobile. This same Application run on Android 4.2 device properly.

Comment: For Android version 2.3.5, its SDK version is 10. Should be okay to install the app. However, is the Android rooted to "pretend" to be another version of Android OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue. In Android Studio, minSDK version in build.gradle file not updated. I changed minSDK from 14 to 8 in build.gradle file. It works great on my HTC device.